# Nodal Analysis: Resistor in front of Node A

Tags: nodal-analysis

In this section from a circuit, Va has two voltages going to it, but also has a resistor going to it as well.

[image]

Most nodal analyses I've seen look like this. So Va is very easy to find. The resistor in the way of the voltage confuses me. What would you do, given the situation.

[image]

This is the full circuit
[image]

Comment: Could you please improve the pictures? First picture: reduce the size and cut it correctly (the right side connection to the 5V source is not shown). Second picture: cut it correctly (is there a resistor or inductor at the top?)

Comment: I've provided the full circuit at the bottom. But I don't see why you would need it, because the solution should be applicable to any given circuit.

Comment: @Redsam121 _"But I don't see why you would need it"_ Schematics are the _de facto_ language among EEs.

Comment: The nodal equation for Va node may look like this: $$\frac{V_A -5V}{100 \Omega}+\frac{V_A  - 20V}{100 \Omega} - 3A =0$$ And notice that you have a supernode here.

Comment: Yes but 5v doesn't have 100 ohms going to it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the entire circuit? Otherwise it would be impossible to help you.

Edit: ok

You know the current in the 10 Ohm resistor (it's 3A). You know the voltage accross the 20 Ohm resistor (it's 5V). So you can compute i with kirchoff current law (it will depends on VA because current in the 5V battery will be shared at VA).

From i you can compute the voltage accross the 100 Ohm resistor. Then by using kirchoff voltage law, you can easily find VA.

Here with formulas:

[image]

Comment: what about nodes b and c? Also there are two 100 ohm resistors in this circuit, which one are you using.

Comment: @Redsam121 i_100ohm refers to the 100 ohm resistor at the left;

i refers to the current in the 100 ohm resistor in the middle.

I don't see where are nodes b and c?

Comment: Node B would be in the middle, C would be on the right.

Comment: Then node B is what I called V_i : it is equal to VA - 5V.

For node C: the voltage accross the 10 Ohm resistor is 3A*10 = 30V. Hence, VC = VB + 30V

Comment: Where did you get the 320V from?

Comment: just multiply i by 100 Ohm : 3A*100Ohm + 20V = 320V